# Relation defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Started studying relations and attempted a very basic problem which I think I have done correctly, can somebody tell me if there are any flaws?Also if a relation is reflexive or transitive can it have trichotomy?I know that if it is symmetric it cannot.

Consider the relation on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $n \simeq m$ iff $n-m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Is the relation Reflexive,symmetric,and transitive?

Attempt:

$n-n=0$ and $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ So reflexive

Suppose $n-m \in \mathbb{Z}$ Then $-(n-m) \in \mathbb{Z}$ So symmetric

Suppose $n-m \in \mathbb{Z}$and $m-p  \in \mathbb{Z}$

then $(n-m)+(m-p) \in   \mathbb{Z}$ so transitive.

Does the relation of trichotomy?

Relation does not have trichotomy since the relation is symmetric so

$nRm$ and $mRn$ are true which contradicts trichotomy

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Everything seems fine! Another reason that you don't have trichotomy is that there are pairs $(n,m)$ such that $n \neq m$ and neither $nRm$ nor $mRn$. E.g. $n=0, m=1/2$. Oh, and if you're being pedantic then, in order for symmetry to imply non-trichotomy, you have to prove that *there is* a pair $(n,m)$ such that $nRm$ and $n \neq m$ (which is of course obvious).

Answer (score 1):

When showing that a relation does *not* have a property, usually the fastest and most obvious way is to give a concrete counterexample. For instance, $1\simeq0$ and $0\simeq1$, or $0\not\simeq\frac12, \frac12\not\simeq0$ and $0\neq\frac12$, either pair proving that the relation doesn't have trichotomy.

Of course, some times general arguments can show impossibilities as well. Such as no relation (on a set with more than one element) being both reflexive and having trichotomy. This is because for a relation $R$ with trichotomy, and any two elements $a,b$, exactly one of $aRb, bRa$ or $a=b$ holds. But for two unequal elements, this breaks reflexivity.

As for the rest, it is correct, but I personally feel it ought to be more explicit: actually spell out exactly what makes the property hold. For symmetry, I would write something along the lines of

> Assume $m\simeq n$. This means $m-n\in\Bbb Z$. But then $n-m=-(m-n)\in\Bbb Z$ as well, so we get $n\simeq m$, showing that the relation is symmetric.

and for transitivity

> Assume $m\simeq n$ and $n\simeq p$. Then $m-n\in\Bbb Z$ and $n-p\in\Bbb Z$. But then $m-p=(m-n)+(n-p)\in\Bbb Z$ as well, showing that the relation is transitive.

In other words, expand a bit more on what exactly it is your doing. Not just write down the central equality of your argument and let the reader full in the rest.

Comment: The textbook I'm using says "notice no relation can be both reflexive and have trichotomy"

Comment: @Eastcoastdancer You're right. I was thinking about antisymmetry. Fixed my answer.